# detect enter on a memo in Delphi

Tags: delphi

hi i am doing a command shell using a memo in Delphi , the problem is to detect the last line written and read the command I need to know how to detect the enter key on a memo.

as I can detect the enter key on a memo ?

Comment: I think you need a bit more than just detecting the enter key, for example backspace. Do you want the user to be able to modify prior commands? Besides that, have you checked out the `OnKey...` events of the `TMemo` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting the enter key in a `TMemo` control is easy. Just add an `OnKeyPress` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    // Do something
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Technically, the `OnKeyPress` event does not provide **virtual key codes**, like `VK_RETURN`, it provides actual **characters** instead, like `#13`.  Virtual key codes are used in the `OnKeyDown/Up` events.  It just HAPPENS that the value of the `VK_RETURN` virtual key code is the same as the character it generates.  That is not true for all virtual key codes, so don't get in the habit of using `VK_...` values in the `OnKeyPress` event, only in the `OnKeyDown/Up` events.

Comment: @Remy: I know. But I am used to use it for `VK_RETURN` because I use it in `TEdit` controls to suppress the beep sound.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: it is *semantically* wrong to use `VK_RETURN` in `OnKeyPress`, even if it happens to "work".  A virtual key code and a translated character are not the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

In the **OnKeypress** event you can check for certain keys and handle them as you wish yourself.  The enter key is one of these keys.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
const
  ENTER = #13;
begin
  case Key of
    ENTER : begin
              // Do something
            end;
  end;
end;
```

By default a **TMemo** has the **WantReturns** property set to *TRUE*.  This means that as well as any response to the key press that you might implement in your code, the **TMemo** will still also receive the key event and add a new line to the content of the memo.

If you do not want this then you can either:

- Set **WantReturns = FALSE**.  you will still get the **KeyPress**
  event for the enter key, but the memo will not add new lines in
  response (they can still be added if the user presses **Ctrl +
  Enter**)

OR

- Keep **WantReturns = TRUE** but set Key to the value #0 for any key
  events which you want to suppress (i.e. prevent from reaching the
  memo control).

An example of this latter approach might look something like this:

```
const
  NO_KEY = #0;
  ENTER  = #13;
begin
  case Key of
    ENTER : begin
              // Do something

              if NOT AddNewLine then
                Key := NO_KEY;
            end;
  end;
end;
```

**NOTE:** The **OnKeyPress** event only allows you to respond to a subset of key events, specifically those that correspond to **CHAR** type values (although this does include some non-printing characters such as *Tab* and *Backspace*, for example).

If you want or need to detect the state of a wider range of non-character keys or to reliably handle key combinations such as **Ctrl+Key** or **Shift+Key** then you will need to query the state of those modifier keys.  However, by the time you are responding to the key event, the state of the modifier keys may have changed and a better approach in that case is to use an alternate event which provides a greater range of key events, including the state of the *Shift* keys (and *Control* keys) at the time of the key event itself, such as **OnKeyDown**.

Comment: Why not use the built-in key constants?

Comment: @Jerry, I guess you are referring to `VK_*` constants. If so, then be careful, because they can be translated to chars with different ordinal value than a `VK_*` key code they had when they entered the initial keyboard event (not in this case all over the world, I guess, but still...).

Comment: @JerryDodge: Because there is no pre-defined key constant for the `ENTER` key (and no, `VK_RETURN` does not count - it is a **virtual* key for use in the `OnKeyDown/Up` events, not the `OnKeyPress` event).  There is a `CR` constant which is the same value (#13), though.

Comment: What TLama and Remy said.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OnKeyDown` event, for example:

```
procedure TForm.Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_Return then
  begin
    // Your code here ...

    // set Key to 0 if you do not want the key
    // to be default-processed by the control...
    Key := 0 ;
  end;
end;
```